# "The opportunity for [x]" or "the opportunity to [x]"?

Tags: prepositions, formal-language

> I am qualified to have the opportunity **for** this beautiful journey for many reasons.
>
> I am qualified to have the opportunity **to** this beautiful journey for many reasons.

Which is more correct in formal English?

Comment: Your question isn't about the preposition after "qualified"; it's about the one after "opportunity". But while "I am qualified to have the opportunity ..." is grammatical, it sounds like you don't know the meaning of "qualified".

Comment: @PeterShor so should i say? `i am qualified for this beautiful journey` ?

Comment: Marco, @Peter means that your question title is incorrect; it says you're wondering about to vs for after *qualified*, but your question text shows it after *opportunity*. I'll edit to correct.

Comment: *[have the] opportunity **to** [noun]* would never be acceptable, but the entire text reads more like a translation than "natural English". I would delete *to have the opportunity*, and replace *this beautiful journey* with something less "flowery" (such as *job*, or perhaps just *opportunity* if OP really wants to include that word).

Comment: @FumbleFingers so it would be better to say `I am qualified to have this opportunity for many reasons` ?

Comment: To be qualified for something means that you have demonstrated (usually by way of a qualification test) to have the necessary skills or knowledge to act in some capacity.  E.g., he is qualified to be a teacher. Or he is qualified to practice medicine, or she is qualified to act as a tour guide etc.  But it doesn't really make sense to be qualified to have an opportunity.  Perhaps you mean you are *thankful* for the opportunity.

Comment: @Jim maybe i dont know what is the meaning of `qulified`, but please does it make sence to say `i deserve to have this great opportunity ` ?

Comment: Yes, I see the sense you are looking for. *deserve* does fit much better, but it may come off sounding a bit pushy or conceited.  You could soften it with an *I think/feel*:  "There are many reasons why I feel that I deserve this opportunity." But this is getting into writing advice.

Answer (score 3):

when you have verb after opportunity you have to use "to".
look at these:

Everyone will have an opportunity **to** ***comment.***
An ankle injury meant she missed the opportunity **to** ***run*** in the qualifying heat.

But when you have noun you have to use "for":

there are far more opportunities now **for** ***school leavers*** than there were fifty years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should say, "I am qualified for this opportunity for many reasons," although I think we could give you more help if we had a better sense of the context.

Comment: this is the whole context `I am very eager to study in England and gain the benefits from a new experience in which I can improve my knowledge and master my skills. Plus, I deserve to have this great opportunity for many reasons.` it is a TOEFL writing essay

Comment: OK, thanks. My husband, an English professor and former writing center director, would probably bite my head off for giving you such direct assistance rather than working with you on process. Are you studying at a university where you could use the services of a writing center? In any case, I'd say "benefit from" instead of "gain the benefits from." Also, "great opportunity" may sound a little bit insincere. Maybe just say "opportunity." Or, perhaps, something like, "This is a great opportunity, and one that I believe I deserve for many reasons." Do you see the difference?

Comment: i dont know, i am just a learner, i learn with no teacher

Comment: Marco, please: we write "I" with an upper-case letter.